# what do 'void,+,-,~,!' in front of function do?

Tags: javascript

From this
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression

```
!function () { /* ... */ }(); 
~function () { /* ... */ }();  
-function () { /* ... */ }(); 
+function () { /* ... */ }(); 
void function () { /* ... */ }();
```

I can't find any information online.

Comment: The Wikipedia article *does* explain it, albeit rather tersely. It's to change the interpreter into *expression mode*, so it wouldn't treat `function() {}` as a declaration.

Comment: I took me ages to get through the jargon. What is “an expression” or a “statement”? What does “invocation” mean? Etc... Once you do, this becomes a lot easier to understand.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes you're right. I'm just started learn JS.I don't know what they're called. I tried to search something like 'js operator' ,'!function() javascript' ,'~function ()' on this site , search on w3schools and everywhere.I found nothing.I used wrong keywords.

Comment: You right, knowing searching with the right terminology is a hard skill to learn.